# Adding days to a date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I can add days to a date just fine for any date in a month in the current month. However, if I select an arrival date of say `2014-06-26` and then select `7` nights (which will roll it over to the next month) It does the correct addition for the days but adds it as if the month is the current month `2014-05-26`. Am I not adding days to a date properly?

```
$('#nights').blur(function() {
        var date = new Date();
        var arrival = parseDate($('#arrivaldate').val());
        var nights = parseInt($('#nights').val());
        date.setDate(arrival.getDate()+nights);
        console.log(date);
        //convert date
        var mon = date.getMonth()+1;
        console.log(mon);
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var day = date.getDate();
        mon = mon < 10 ? "0"+mon : mon;
        day = day < 10 ? "0"+day : day;     

        $('#departdate').val(year+'-'+mon+'-'+day);
    });
```

Comment: _“but adds it as if the month is the current month”_ – the month _is_ the current month, because you are doing the addition on the _current_ date, and not your arrival date …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @CBroe pointed out in comments.

`var date = new Date();`  initialized `date` from the **current time**

`date.setDate(arrival.getDate()+nights);` sets the day of month in `date` to the day of month in `arrival`  and added +nights.

If today is in May, `date` is in May, and if `arrival` is in June, the 2nd line does not set the month in `date` to June.

Try this:

```
var arrival = parseDate($('#arrivaldate').val());
var depart = new Date(arrival);
var nights = parseInt($('#nights').val());
depart.setDate(arrival.getDate()+nights);
console.log(depart);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I guess it was a case of "I've been staring at this way too long".

Comment: Also note `parseDate()` is not part of standard Javascript.  You might have a function parseDate in a library somewhere.... or maybe it should be [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse)